# Xamarin.Auth : Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider [xamarin forms - Android]

Tags: android, xamarin.auth

I'm following this sample tutorial for https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/

After download the sample, I follow the instructions and change all my clientID endpoint.I got into the Google Sign In page and browser manage to close. After browser close, it always got into OnAuthError and error message is "Error authenticating : invalid_request"

[image: error message]

I couldn't get the OnAuthCompleted fired. Its always got into OnAuthError.

```
 void OnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string clientId = null;
            string redirectUri = null;

            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    clientId = Constants.iOSClientId;
                    redirectUri = Constants.iOSRedirectUrl;
                    break;

                case Device.Android:
                    clientId = Constants.AndroidClientId;
                    redirectUri = Constants.AndroidRedirectUrl;
                    break;
            }

            var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId,
                null,
                Constants.Scope,
                new Uri(Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
                new Uri(redirectUri),
                new Uri(Constants.AccessTokenUrl),
                null,
                true);

            authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
            authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;

            AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

            var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
            presenter.Login(authenticator);
        }

        async void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
            if (authenticator != null)
            {
                authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
                authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
            }

            User user = null;
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the user is authenticated, request their basic user data from Google
                // UserInfoUrl = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
                var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri(Constants.UserInfoUrl), null, e.Account);
                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                if (response != null)
                {
                    // Deserialize the data and store it in the account store
                    // The users email address will be used to identify data in SimpleDB
                    string userJson = await response.GetResponseTextAsync();
                    user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(userJson);
                }

                if (account != null)
                {
                    store.Delete(account, Constants.AppName);
                }

                await store.SaveAsync(account = e.Account, Constants.AppName);
                await DisplayAlert("Email address", user.Email, "OK");
            }
        }

        void OnAuthError(object sender, AuthenticatorErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
            if (authenticator != null)
            {
                authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
                authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Authentication error: " + e.Message);
        }
```

I have read through all the related links. The closest questions I got from SO is this  : [Xamarin.Forms Google API Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684166/xamarin-forms-google-api-authenticating-users-with-an-identity-provider)
but it still failed after configure the setting and update my packages. I'm using Xamarin.Auth 1.5.0.3 (latest stable version)

Any real hero outside can run this tutorial and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I am using Type : "Others" at the Google Console Developer website. When I switch back the Type: "Android". It's working. 
[image: Google Console]